# How to get user who is requesting a page

Tags: android, google-app-engine

I've been trying to get the email of the person who is sending a GET to AppEngine for hours I can't get that working.

What I'm trying to do is:

A client request a GET to an URL from Android.
AppEngine returns XML depending on the user making the request.

I'm using [AERC library](https://code.google.com/p/aerc/) from [Tim Bray](http://www.tbray.org/ongoing/When/201x/2011/09/29/AERC) to authenticate using a token that android provides.

```
public void run() {
        if(client == null){
            final AccountManager mgr = AccountManager.get(mActivity);
            Account[] accts = mgr.getAccountsByType("com.google");
            client = new AppEngineClient(APP_URI, accts[0], mActivity);
        }
        Log.i(tag, "Respuesta de auth: "+new String(client.get(AUTH_URI, null).body));
    }
```

On the server side I have this:

```
UserService userService = UserServiceFactory.getUserService();

        if (userService.getCurrentUser() != null) {
            ret = "<tag>User userSErvice: "+userService.getCurrentUser() + "</tag>";
        }else{
            ret = "<tag>User userSErvice: null</tag>";
        }
        if (request.getUserPrincipal() != null) {
            ret += "<tag>User request: "+request.getUserPrincipal() + "</tag>";
        }else{
            ret += "<tag>User request: null</tag>";
        }
```

I'm using userService.getCurrentUser() and request.getUserPrincipal() because I don't know what method is which have to work. Both return null.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. 
I had to add security contraints on web.xml like this:

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <url-pattern>/yourservlet/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>*</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

And you have to request to an https to get the user from appengine